# How to send global variable value in request default headers Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I would like to send a global variable value as default request header in every ajax request. Below is my code which i tried

```
// fetches new token on every response
   Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', function(conn, response, options) {
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(response) && !Ext.isEmpty(response.getResponseHeader("Token"))) {
               MySharedData.myToken = response.getResponseHeader("Token");
            }
        });

//sends the new token on every request for validation
Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
            newToken: MySharedData.myToken
        };


Ext.define('MySharedData', { 
    singleton: true, 
    myToken: ''
});
```

currently after request the value is set properly in the global variable. But when i try to send the value in the default header in the request. It is being sent as blank value. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

These are the request headers field you can add ([refer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_requests.htm) Request Header Fields topic):

•    Accept-Charset

•   Accept-Encoding

•   Accept-Language

•   Authorization

•   Expect

•   From

•   Host

**....**

•   User-Agent

Adding anything random is not a good approach instead you can use extraParams to send any such data.

`extraParams: {
       newToken : MySharedData.myToken
}`

If it is an Authorization token then you can add to the “Authorization” Request Header Field. Send in a defaultHeader json. Refer [setDefaultHeaders](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Connection.html#method-setDefaultHeaders) method for setting the default header field once you create an instance for the request.